# Pycharm: make it display a huge dict properly?

Tags: python, pycharm

I needed to have a huge dict as a variable, so I created it automatically by running some Python code that generates the dict, then I said `print(dict)`, copied everything, and then simply wrote in my file `my_dict =`  and copy-pasted the code in there.

Problem is, that looks MESSY. There's about 1000 key value pairs, and they're all jumbled up when I copy-paste it like that.

I was hoping for Pycharm to automatically format it nicely, i.e. something like

```
my_dict = {
           key: value,
           key: value,
           ...

}
```

Surely this functionality should be available?

To be clear, I am talking about formatting INSIDE the editor. Not when printing out the dict.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html

Comment: PyCharm should do that when pasting but in any case you can right click on the file and then "Reformat Code" (or `Ctrl+Alt+L`).

Comment: You could also `from pprint import pprint` and then `pprint(dict)` to pretty-print it (and then copy it).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily format your output like this.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(f"    {key}: {value}")
```

If you want value to look like 'string' you can do something like this.

```
for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print(f"    {key}: '{value}'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not print it to a file? E.g. for a JSON like structure via

```
with open(filename, 'w') as file:
    file.write('your_json ='+ json.dumps( your_json, indent=2))
```

The indent specifies the formatting.